# Is it possible to add private data to a GtkWidget?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

Is it possible to add *private data* to a `GtkWidget`?

**Background:**

I have many `GtkCheckBotton`s, all these widgets are connected to the same callback. In the callback, I would like to handle the widgets private data (or at least distinguish between the widgets).

**Example:**

```
// checkbox signal callback
void on_checkbox_tcoggled(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    MyClass* me = data;
    MyPrivateData* priv = widget->priv;  // ???

    MyClass_foo(me, priv);
}
```

Comment: See my comment to @el.pescado's answer. You have some errors.

Comment: @unwind You are right, thanks!

Comment: Why not gtkmm instead since you are mixing gtk (c) with C++?

Comment: @Joel I can not use gtkmm, because I am using a c compiler. Where am I mixing C with C++?

Comment: There's nothing wrong mixing C libraries with C++, but there's a reason that there are GTK ports. I only commented as an alternative and get the advantage of C++ with gtkmm. My $0.02.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to add private data to a GtkWidget?

You can use functions [`g_object_set_data`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-data) and [`g_object_get_data`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get-data) to add arbitrary data to any `GObject`.

```
MyPrivateData *priv = ...
g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "my private data", priv);

// ...

void on_checkbox1_toggled(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data) {
    MyClass* me = data;
    MyPrivateData* priv = (MyPrivateData*) g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(widget), "my private data");

    MyClass_foo(me, priv);
}
```

Comment: The second argument to the callback is just `gpointer`, not `gpointer *`. And since that's just a `void *`, the cast is not necessary.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice it when copying code from question.

Comment: Many thanks, I like this solution, works like a charm.